# FindEdgeCut with weighted graphs

Tags: graphs-and-networks

If I want to find a minimum cut between two nodes in a weighted graph, I would use FindEdgeCut as follows:

```
g = Graph[{1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 
    3 \[UndirectedEdge] 4}, EdgeWeight -> {2, 3, 5, 123}];
FindEdgeCut[g,1,4]
```

This function, however, returns the edge 3-4, so obviously the edge weights have not been considered.

I can find the minimum cut by using the maximum flow and so on, but I was wondering whether this error is more easily fixable or maybe it's just me and I don't see the error.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) [`Read the FAQs`](http://tinyurl.com/cacvex2)!  3) When you see good Q&A, vote them up by [`clicking the gray triangles`](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.  ALSO, remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [`by clicking the checkmark sign`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Comment: Appears to be incorrect in version 9.0.0 and fixed in version 9.0.1.

Answer (score 2):

> "*so obviously the edge weights have not been considered*"

The edge weights **have** been considered. It can be seen from careful reading the **Details** [**section of documentation**](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FindEdgeCut.html) on **FindEdgeCut** and comparing different examples. So what does FindEdgeCut do?

- An edge cut of a graph g is a set of edges whose deletion from g disconnects g.
- For weighted graphs, FindEdgeCut gives an edge cut with the **smallest** sum of edge weights.

Now if you compare this

```
Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 1 <-> 3, 3 <-> 4}, EdgeWeight -> {2, 3, 5, 123}] // FindEdgeCut
```

> {1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3}

with this

```
Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 1 <-> 3, 3 <-> 4}, EdgeWeight -> {2, 3, 5, 1}] // FindEdgeCut
```

> {3 <-> 4}

you will understand how the EdgeWeight is taken account.

Comment: Then maybe this is a version issue, I am using Mathematica 9.0.0.0 and while your second example does work, the first one does not. Also, I noticed a slight error in my question. What I actually wanted to do was FindEdgeCut[g,1,4], if that changes anything.

Comment: @Thomas `1,4` wouldn't change anything for this specific graph. I recommend contacting [Wolfram Support](http://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/) for version issue.

Comment: Just wanted to note that FindEdgeCut is totally unreliable with weights, even in 12.1 ... it's simply not safe to use because it's impossible to decide if it will return a correct result. It's one of those long-standing `Graph` bugs I keep complaining about.